# Recursion gives unexpected/wrong output?

Tags: java, recursion

So I was doing a recursion challenge on [codingbat](http://codingbat.com/java) and came across the "bunny ears" problem where we have a number of bunnies and each bunny has two big floppy ears. We want to compute the total number of ears across all the bunnies recursively (without loops or multiplication).

The solution apparently is quite simple:

```
public int bunnyEars(int bunnies)
{
    if(bunnies == 0)
        return 0;
    return 2+bunnyEars(bunnies-1);
}
```

But I am not able to understand. If we pass 2 in the bunnyEars(2) method the 
recursive part bunnyEars(bunnies-1); should have 1 left in the bracket after subtraction and thus 2+(1); which should be equal to 3 and not 4.
But the output comes as 4. So how does recursion actually work in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not 2+(1), it is 2+numberOfEarsOfBunnies(1) == 2+2.
I renamed the function a little to make it more obvious.

Or even more into detail:

numberOfEarsOfBunnies(2)==
2+numberOfEarsOfBunnies(1)==
2+(2+numberOfEarsOfBunnies(0))==
2+(2+0)==
2+2==
4

Comment: Ok now got it!!

Comment: My pleasure. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> if we pass 2 in the bunnyEars(2) method the recursive part bunnyEars(bunnies-1); should have 1 left in the bracket after subtraction and thus 2+(1); should be equal to 3 and not 4.

It seems you're misreading the expression.  The line of code in question says

```
return 2+bunnyEars(bunnies-1);
```

Now you call `bunnyEars(2)`, so `bunnies == 2`; and then you reach this line of code.

```
return 2+bunnyEars(bunnies-1);
```

resolves to

```
return 2+bunnyEars(2-1);
```

or

```
return 2+bunnyEars(1);
```

So a second instance of the `bunnyEars()` function starts running, with `bunnies == 1`.  It reaches that same line of code, and this time

```
return 2+bunnyEars(bunnies-1);
```

is

```
return 2+bunnyEars(1-1);
```

or

```
return 2+bunnyEars(0);
```

So a *third* instance of `bunnyEars()` gets running, with `bunnies == 0`; but this matches your base case, so you just return `0` ; this time we don't recurse.  So back up a level we find that

```
return 2+bunnyEars(0);
```

is

```
return 2+0; // because bunnyEars(0) returned 0
```

so that instance returns 2.  And that means

```
return 2+bunnyEars(1);
```

becomes

```
return 2+2; // because bunnyEars(1) returned 2
```

And of course `2+2` is `4`, the correct answer.

It seems as though you applied the `-1` to the return value of the recursive `bunnyEars()` call, but the code says to apply it to the parameter you're sending in, not to the return value.